# PayPal::SDK::Permissions::API The application is not authorized for the user

Tags: ruby, paypal

My application is requesting permission for `TRANSACTION_DETAILS`, using paypal-sdk-permissions (1.96.2) gem.
Everything works fine in sandbox but fails when going live:

```
@errorId=550006, 
@domain="PLATFORM", 
@subdomain="Application", 
@severity="Error", 
@category="Application", 
@message="The application is not authorized for the user"
```

**EDIT**

It seems I was using an APP ID submitted from a different Paypal account. After fixing that I got:

```
@errorId=550001 @message="User is not allowed to perform this action"
```

I have submitted a new app with the corresponding permissions and the status is `Approved Conditionally`.
Usually how long does it take to get a response from Paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After only a couple of hours my app got approved.
Now everything works as expected.