# PayPal System error 550006 in Android app

Tags: android, paypal, billing, android-billing

I am trying to make an android app with in-app purchases available through PayPal.  Everything works fine in the sandbox mode, but when I switch to live mode I get this error:

Payment Failed
System error (550006). Please try again later.

The only documentation that I can find says that this error means, "The application is not authorized for the App caller."

Here are the changes that I have made going from sandbox to live. Am I missing something?

- My app's status on PayPal has been 'Approved' for about 24 hours. This post ([PayPal::SDK::Permissions::API The application is not authorized for the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766543/paypalsdkpermissionsapi-the-application-is-not-authorized-for-the-user)) suggests that it only took about 2 hours.
- I have changed my configuration environment from PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE.
- I have changed my Client ID to the live ID.
- I have changed my receiver email from sandbox to live.

One concern that I have is that I am trying to make the payment from my wife's paypal account to my own and they use the same checking account. However I don't think this is the problem because if I try to send from my account to my account I get error 579033 ("The sender and each receiver must have different accounts").

Any ideas?

Comment: A 550006 error has the message "UNAUTHORIZED_APPLICATION_USER". Are you able to provide a copy of the request you're submitting and the response? If there is a correlation ID and a timestamp I can look it up

Comment: Thanks for your respnse.  I am just using the PayPalAndroidSDK.jar to make the calls in conjunction with the sample code provided with the SDK.  I'm not sure how to extract the information that you have requested.  I have looked in logcat but I don't see any relevant information.

Comment: Ryan, did you ever get this issue resolved with PayPal?

Comment: Nope, still waiting for their reply.  Last I heard, they know there is a problem, and their engineers are looking into it.

Comment: The problem has been resolved. PayPal recently released PayPalAndroidSDK.jar version 1.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. PayPal recently released PayPalAndroidSDK.jar version 1.0.3.  It can be downloaded from GitHub: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK